# Xquery to concatenate names if available

Tags: xslt, concatenation, xquery

we have an incoming message with Name field as below, where "GivenName" field is unbounded:

```
<Name>
  <Surname>LOUIS</Surname>
  <GivenName>John</GivenName>
  <GivenName>Andy</GivenName>
</Name>
```

we need to pass the message to other end system as:

```
<Name>
  <FullName>LOUIS, John Andy</FullName>
</Name>
```

so, if the GivenName field is not present in input, the transformation should produce:

```
<Name>
  <FullName>LOUIS</FullName>
</Name>
```

and if multipe GivenName is present in the input it should concatenate all by seperating with a space.

I tried using concatenate function but its not giving desired result.
I tried using:

```
<ns1:FullName>{ fn:concat($SubmittedBy/ns1:Name/ns1:Surname,", ", (for $GivenName in $SubmittedBy/ns1:Name/ns1:GivenName return fn:concat(data($GivenName), "")) ) }</ns1:FullName>
```

but its producing something like:

```
<Name>
  <FullName>LOUIS, JohnAndy</FullName>
</Name>
```

I am having trouble in separating GivenName with space if they are present.

Could someone please provide any suggestion.

TIA,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fn:concat($str1, $str2, ...)` expects a single string per argument and concatenates all of them into one string. For concatenating a *sequence* of strings and specifying what should go between the parts, you can use [`fn:string-join($strs, $joiner)`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-string-join):

```
string-join(('foo', 'bar', 'baz'), '::')
```

produces the string `foo::bar::baz`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Leo, thanks a ton to Leo, I used below code and it solves to adding GivenName only if it present with space delimited.

```
{  fn:string-join((fn:concat($Name/ns1:Surname,","),$Name/ns1:GivenName), ' ')}
```

I needed a 'comma' after the Surname, so I had to hardcode it, so If no GivenName is present it give Surname with a comma "LOUIS,"
so outputs are as below, based on availability of GivenName in the request:

```
<FullName>LOUIS,</FullName>
<FullName>LOUIS, John</FullName>
<FullName>LOUIS, John Andy</FullName>
```

Ideal case would be to add a Comma only if GivenName is present.